# How to read directory and filter files and then echo them out?

Tags: php

Hello everyone im trying to read a directory called people which is filled with `php,html,png,jpeg` and other formats. I am trying to filter the files i want the `php` and `html` files and then echo them out.

Here is my attempt which didn't work since it didn't `echo` any files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Khviii ICT</title>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center" ><h1>Welcome to KHVIII ICT</h1></div>
<?php
$dir="/people";
$allowed_view= array("php","html");
$files=scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
        $filexplosion=strtolower(end(explode('.',$file)));
    if (in_array($allowed_view,$filexplosion)) 
        {
    echo $file;
    } 
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With the `glob()` function, a suffix specifier `.{jpeg,html}` and `GLOB_BRACE`.

Comment: `/people` is likely wrong - you'll need to use an absolute filesystem path. Your web host or admin will be able to tell you that path.

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250586/deleting-all-files-in-except-the-one-running-the-delete-code/17250780#17250780

Comment: also, don't use explode/array operations just to get a file extension. `$ext = path_info($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` is far more efficient.

Comment: Thanks all i have tried and learnt more things but glob() worked for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few goes i have worked it out i am using gelb().
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>khvii index</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
foreach (glob("people/"."*.php",GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
    $phpexplode = end(explode("/",$filename));
    echo'<a href="'.$filename.'"><input type="button" value="'.$phpexplode.'"></a><br />';
}
foreach (glob("people/"."*.html",GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
    $htmlexplode = end(explode("/",$filename));
    echo'<a href="'.$filename.'"><input type="button" value="'.$htmlexplode.'"></a><br />';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

directory path is not correct and in_array arguments are not in order. Corrected php code is as below:

```
    $dir = __DIR__ . "/people";
    $allowed_view = array("php", "html");
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $filexplosion = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));
        if (in_array($filexplosion, $allowed_view)) {
            echo $file;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$files=scandir($dir);
echo "I have found " . count($files) . " files<br>"; // Are you sure there are files found?
foreach ($files as $file)
{
$filexplosion = substr($file, strrpos($file, "."));
echo $filexplosion; // just to check if you're getting the right value
if (in_array($allowed_view,$filexplosion)){
  echo $file;
}
```