# Duplicate files in php

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I am wondering how I can create a function that states:

*if a file of name Setup.php exist twice in a folder and/or it's associated sub folders, return a message. if a file with the extension .css exists more then once in a folder or any of its sub folders, return a message*

This function would have to be recursive, due to sub folders. and its fine to hard code 'Setup.php' or '.css' as they are the only things looked for.

What I currently have is a bit messy but does the trick (refactoring will come after I figure out this issue)

```
protected function _get_files($folder_name, $type){
    $actual_dir_to_use = array();
    $array_of_files[] = null;
    $temp_array = null;
    $path_info[] = null;

    $array_of_folders = array_filter(glob(CUSTOM . '/' .$folder_name. '/*'), 'is_dir');
    foreach($array_of_folders as $folders){
        $array_of_files = $this->_fileHandling->dir_tree($folders);
        if(isset($array_of_files) && !empty($array_of_files)){
            foreach($array_of_files as $files){
                $path_info = pathinfo($files);
                if($type == 'css'){
                    if($path_info['extension'] == 'css'){
                        $actual_dir_to_use[] = $folders;
                    }
                }

                if($type == 'php'){
                    if($path_info['filename'] == 'Setup' && $path_info['extension'] == 'php'){
                        $temp_array[] = $folders;
                        $actual_dir_to_use[] = $folders;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $array_of_files = array();
        $path_info = array();
    }

    return $actual_dir_to_use;      
}
```

if you pass in say, **packages** and **php** into the function I will look through the packages folder and return all the sub-folder names, (eg: `path/to/apples, path/to/bananas, path/to/fruit, path/to/cat, path/to/dog`) that contain Setup with an extension of php.

The problem is if apples/ contains more then one Setup.php then I get: `path/to/apples, path/to/apples, path/to/bananas, path/to/fruit, path/to/cat, path/to/dog`

So I need to modify this function, or write a separate one, that sates the above sudo code.

**problem?** I don't know where to begin. So I am here asking for help.

Comment: Bit of a mess. Maybe try the example by `alvaro at demogracia` on this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250586/deleting-all-files-in-except-the-one-running-the-delete-code/17250780#17250780

Comment: neither of these answers help, Marcs is accomplished in my function and @bystwn22 your answer is about deleting files. I guess I could just check the `$actual_dir_to_use` for duplicates...

Comment: @TheWebs no, its not, you are mistaken, thats just a class file, which returns all files and subfolders in your given path, so you can add a callback to check the files or folders, let me post this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can find the class `ipDirLiterator` here - [deleting all files in except the one running the delete code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250586/deleting-all-files-in-except-the-one-running-the-delete-code/17250780#17250780).
i hope you got it.

```
<?php
  $directory  = dirname( __FILE__ )."/test/";
  $actual_dir_to_use  = array();
  $to_find  = "php";

  $literator  = new ipDirLiterator( $directory, array( "file" => "file_literator", "dir" => "dir_literator" ) );
  $literator->literate();

  function file_literator( $file ) {
    global $actual_dir_to_use, $to_find;
    // use print_r( $file ) to see what all are inside $file

    $filename = $file["filename"]; // the file name
    $filepath = $file["pathname"]; // absolute path to file
    $folder   = $file["path"]; // the folder where the current file contains
    $extens   = strtolower( $file["extension"] );

    if ( $to_find === "php" && $filename === "Setup.php" ) {
      $actual_dir_to_use[]  = $folder;
    }
    if ( $to_find === "css" && $extens === "css" ) {
      $actual_dir_to_use[]  = $folder;
    }
  }

  function dir_literator( $file ) {}

  print_r( $actual_dir_to_use );

  // or check
  if ( count( $actual_dir_to_use ) > 1 ) {
    // here multiple files
  }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Q: Is this a homework assignment?

Assuming "no", then:

1) No, the function *doesn't* need to be recursive

2) Under Linux, you could find matching files like this: `find /somefolder -name somefile -print`

3) Similarly, you can detect if a match occurs zero, once or more than once in the path like this:

`find /somefolder -name somefile -print|wc -l`

Comment: No. Personal project. 1) please explain why it doesnt have to be recusive. I am looking to see if a folder has multiple Setup.php files. 2) this is not for some linux terminal. This for loading packages, each package has a Setup.php file, each package should only have ONE Setup.php file.